# Parse an HTML part using jsoup

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup

i need to parse table_stato_dati (http://as777.brt.it/vas/sped_det_show.hsm?referer=sped_numspe_par.htm&Nspediz=031000032043&RicercaNumeroSpedizione=Ricerca):

```
<table class="table_stato_dati">
                        <caption><label id="diz_386" title="Stati">Stati</label></caption>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th><label id="diz_85" title="Data">Data</label></th>
                                <th><label id="diz_273" title="Ora">Ora</label></th>
                                <th><label id="diz_305" title="Filiale">Filiale</label></th>
                                <th><label id="diz_387" title="Stato">Stato</label></th>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td style="white-space: nowrap; width: 1%">26.01.2015</td>
                                <td style="white-space: nowrap; width: 1%">10.42</td>
                                <td style="text-align: left; width: 35%">PORDENONE (069)</td>
                                <td style="text-align: left;">CONSEGNATA</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr class="riga_pari">
                                <td style="white-space: nowrap; width: 1%">26.01.2015</td>
                                <td style="white-space: nowrap; width: 1%"></td>
                                <td style="text-align: left; width: 35%">PORDENONE (069)</td>
                                <td style="text-align: left;">MESSA IN CONSEGNA</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td style="white-space: nowrap; width: 1%">23.01.2015</td>
                                <td style="white-space: nowrap; width: 1%">11.29</td>
                                <td style="text-align: left; width: 35%">PORDENONE (069)</td>
                                <td style="text-align: left;">LASCIATO AVVISO</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr class="riga_pari">
                                <td style="white-space: nowrap; width: 1%">23.01.2015</td>
                                <td style="white-space: nowrap; width: 1%"></td>
                                <td style="text-align: left; width: 35%">PORDENONE (069)</td>
                                <td style="text-align: left;">MESSA IN CONSEGNA</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td style="white-space: nowrap; width: 1%">23.01.2015</td>
                                <td style="white-space: nowrap; width: 1%">08.36</td>
                                <td style="text-align: left; width: 35%">PORDENONE (069)</td>
                                <td style="text-align: left;">ARRIVATA IN FILIALE</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr class="riga_pari">
                                <td style="white-space: nowrap; width: 1%">21.01.2015</td>
                                <td style="white-space: nowrap; width: 1%">21.00</td>
                                <td style="text-align: left; width: 35%">CATANIA (031)</td>
                                <td style="text-align: left;">PARTITA</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td style="white-space: nowrap; width: 1%">21.01.2015</td>
                                <td style="white-space: nowrap; width: 1%">18.00</td>
                                <td style="text-align: left; width: 35%">CATANIA (031)</td>
                                <td style="text-align: left;">RITIRATA</td>
                            </tr>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

My actual code is:

```
public static void TestParse (String trackingCode){
            Document doc;
            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect("http://as777.brt.it/vas/sped_det_show.hsm?referer=sped_numspe_par.htm&Nspediz=031000032043"+trackingCode+"&RicercaNumeroSpedizione=Ricerca").get();

                Elements table = doc.select("table.table_stato_dati");
                System.out.print(table);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

How can i do? Thank you.

---

I need to have only     orderly text about my shipment. I've modified my code:

```
Elements table = doc.select("table.table_stato_dati");
            String text = table.text();
            System.out.println(text);
```

but i cant modified the organization! i want something like this:

```
17.12.2014  11.35   REGGIO CALABRIA (017)   CONSEGNATA
17.12.2014      REGGIO CALABRIA (017)   MESSA IN CONSEGNA
17.12.2014  07.54   REGGIO CALABRIA (017)   ARRIVATA IN FILIALE
15.12.2014  21.00   BRESCIA (093)   PARTITA
15.12.2014  18.00   BRESCIA (093)   RITIRATA
```

not like this:

```
Stati Data Ora Filiale Stato 17.12.2014 11.35 REGGIO CALABRIA (017) CONSEGNATA 17.12.2014 REGGIO CALABRIA (017) MESSA IN CONSEGNA 17.12.2014 07.54 REGGIO CALABRIA (017) ARRIVATA IN FILIALE 15.12.2014 21.00 BRESCIA (093) PARTITA 15.12.2014 18.00 BRESCIA (093) RITIRATA
```

Comment: What do you mean by parse?  Can you tell us more information and also what it is that isn't working?

Comment: i've explained my goal, read answer #0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        Elements trs = doc.select("table.table_stato_dati").select("tr:has(td)");
        for (Element tr : trs) {
            Elements tds = tr.select("td");
            for (Element td : tds) {
                System.out.print(td.text()+" ");                
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```